# How do I return data from Pandas DataFrame to be returned by Django's JsonResponse?

Tags: python, django, pandas, jsonresponse, to-json

The answer to this is probably something really simple, but after hours of searching, I really could not find it.

I am trying to return a JsonResponse using Django from a pandas dataframe. One of the many things I've tried is the following:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import pandas as pd

@csrf_exempt
def do_request(request):
    result = pd.DataFrame({'bla':[1,2,3],'bla2':['a','b','c']}).to_json(orient='records')
    return JsonResponse(result, safe = False)
```

The below ends up returning:

`"[{\"bla\":1,\"bla2\":\"a\"},{\"bla\":2,\"bla2\":\"b\"},{\"bla\":3,\"bla2\":\"c\"}]"`

when in fact I want it to return:

`'[{"bla":1,"bla2":"a"},{"bla":2,"bla2":"b"},{"bla":3,"bla2":"c"}]'`

Comment: what do you get for result if you dont parse the data through pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass python objects (dictionary or list for example) as `JsonResponse` data. But `to_json` return string. So try to parse it:

```
import json

@csrf_exempt
def do_request(request):
    result = pd.DataFrame({'bla':[1,2,3],'bla2':['a','b','c']}).to_json(orient='records')
    return JsonResponse(json.loads(result), safe = False)
```

Comment: This has been very helpful.  I was missing the "json.loads()" call in my JsonResponse(), and the result kept coming as a string.  Thanks!